# IE7 Absolute Div within Relative Div vanishes. z-index does not solve issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, position, z-index

Every question I've found on SO lists the z-index fix as the solution. This, unfortunately, does not seem to work for me.

Here's my structure:

- body
- div wrapper

  - div header
  - div main

    - div page-container

      - *div page-background-image*

        - div page-bottom-gradient
    - div primary

      - div left-menu
    - div outer-container
    - etc...
  - div footer

Here's the CSS

```
body {
color: #666;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
background: url(images/bg-stripes.gif) repeat bottom left;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
#wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1280px;
padding-top: 30px;
background: transparent;
vertical-align: baseline;
z-index: 0;
}
#main {
position: relative;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
background: #DDD;
z-index: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1280px;
}
#page-container {
padding: 0 0 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
#page-background-image {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 460px;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

It appears that the bold section within the structure above is being placed behind the main div. Removing "position: absolute;" from #page-background-image fixes the issue, but obviously removes the absolute position and screws up the layout. Setting a z-index for each element in the tree does not change a thing, regardless of whether I use high-to-low indexes or low-to-high. Could there be another issue that's causing this effect? I'd rather not resort to setting this as a background image, since the image is pulled and placed dynamically.

Comment: please post a live example with some sample text inside :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that there was a floating div inside this tree of other divs. That floating div killed every ancestor that not static (which went until #main). The solution was to add an empty div immediately before the floating div.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that if you are applying `z-index`, you must also apply `position` as `relative` or `absolute`. By default, a `div` has this set to `static` so `z-index` is ignored.

On `#main` you have a `z-index` applied, but not `position` - this could be causing a problem.

Comment: Even after adding relative positions to the divs, everything on top of #main is still pushed to the back. I also tried low-to-high and high-to-low z-indexes on the div tree, which did nothing in IE7. I'll try to get an example up that I can link to.